# Access 30-Pin connector with code

Tags: ios, iphone, dock, connector, mfi

I am trying to set one pin of the old iPhone 30-Pin Connect from low to high so the best would be from 0V to 3,3V. Is that possible with a simple PodBreakout board like this?

https://www.sparkfun.com/products/8295

If not can you send a constant voltage out of the iPhones audio jack (This could be a good method too, cause now apple used its 9-Pin Lightning Connector).

I already searched the web, some say you have to jailbreak your iDevice, some say you need an authentication Chip, and some say it works flawlessly without an authentication chip, but I cant find any help online.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this question belongs on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "send a constant voltage" out of the audio jack. There is a series capacitor there that filters out DC and very low frequency signal components.

To get proper help on this you can [apply for the MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/). I think it's free for educational purposes. It's under 100$ for sure. There is an NDA involved.

If you want to avoid the MFi you can always use [BLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) to communicate with periphery.

Or try to implement software FSK (or DTMF) modem on one side and a hardware one on the other side (using the audio lines).

Since it seems you simply want so see a binary (on/off) signal - you could generate a fixed pitch tone in the app (2kHz for example) and use a narrow-band filter on the hardware side (audio-jack connection).

Or maybe (to make sure your app is present *on the other side* a 2kHz tone would mean 0 and a 4kHz tone could stand for 1.

The *authentication chip* (and an MFi license)) you are talking about is needed when you try to communicate with the iOs device:

- via BT (excluding BLE)
- via USB (30 pin connector or lighting connector)
- via UART (30 pin connector or lighting connector)